# AngularJS starter stuck

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Just need an explanation on why this is not working? Im trying to follow tutorials from tutorial points. The first and second model do working fine. But not for third model. Can someone explain to me why it is not working? Thanks in advance.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>

..........

<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="machineController">

  <input type="text" ng-model="anyText.first" placeholder="any text here" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="anyText.second" placeholder="any text here" />

  <span>{{ anyText.third() }}</span>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    app.controller('machineController', function($scope) {
      $scope.anyText = {
        first: "This is first default text",
        second: "This is second default text",

        third: function() {
          $object = $scope.anyText;
          var newtext = anyText.first + " ::: " + anyText.second;
          return newtext;
        }

      };
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What is `$object`?

Comment: `Error: ReferenceError: anyText is not defined` <- Error logs are a programmer's best friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must replace this line

`var newtext = anyText.first + " ::: " + anyText.second;`

with

```
var newtext = $object.first + " ::: " + $object.second;
```

as `anyText` variable is not defined

```html
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>


<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="machineController">

 <input type="text" ng-model="anyText.first" placeholder="any text here"/>
 <input type="text" ng-model="anyText.second" placeholder="any text here"/>

 <span>{{ anyText.third() }}</span>

 <script>
  var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

  app.controller('machineController',function($scope){
      $scope.anyText = {
          first: "This is first default text",
          second: "This is second default text",

          third: function(){
              $object = $scope.anyText;
              var newtext = $object.first + " ::: " + $object.second;
              return newtext;
          }

      };
  });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`anyText.first` and `anyText.second` is not being referenced by the `$scope`. 
Since you are using `$object` to reference `$scope.anyText`, you can try to change your code like this:

```js
$object = $scope.anyText;
var newtext = $object.first + " ::: " + $object.second;
return newtext;
```

Here is a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1dtKDseuIqt3k3UoeEOA

Answer (score 0):

You also replace those 3 lines with a simple 1 line as below

```
 return $scope.anyText.first + " ::: " + $scope.anyText.second;
```

Complete code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>

..........

<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="machineController">

    <input type="text" ng-model="anyText.first" placeholder="any text here" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="anyText.second" placeholder="any text here" />

    <span>{{ anyText.third() }}</span>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

        app.controller('machineController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.anyText = {
                first: "This is first default text",
                second: "This is second default text",

                third: function () {
                    return $scope.anyText.first + " ::: " + $scope.anyText.second;
                }

            };
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```